# removing window from modalviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I launch a modal view controller and in its init I have the following code:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I need the viewController for entering some data in it. How can I release the window and viewController so that I can go back to the viewController that launched the modal view controller? At this point, after I'm done doing what I need in the modal view, I am trying:

```
[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[window removeFromSuperview];
```

but just end up with the modal view's parent (the one that lanched the modal view) just frozen(it's not really frozen, it is just not user interactible because there are the window and view controller in front of it and the view controller doesn't have size and background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS app should only contain one `UIWindow`.
 And you can easily present `UIViewController` with in viewController

```
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:animated];
```

Then just call in that viewController to dismiss it:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have not been very clear about the problem, was trying to keep it simple. The class that is calling the view to be set is not a viewcontroller(it's a SHKSharer from ShareKit). so when i set UIWindow i actually need to set it. the question remaining is:How can i remove it?

Comment: Sharekit uses UIViewControllers, and even if you build your own view, you should not adde an UIWindow. You will need to make the old window key again. But is this is wrong on so many levels.

Comment: i've added some features to sharekit(integrated foursquare) and the official example is with a UIWindow

Comment: Get this version of sharekit: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit and this https://github.com/everdune/ShareKit/tree/75574d5f80abeff7c41500d415252a7d72d2fd2d/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/FoursquareV2